# recursively get all files except the hidden ones with pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I would like to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to recursively iterate over all *files* of a given path, except those which are hidden or are in hidden directories. E.g., from

```
|
|- a.txt
|- .b.txt
|- a/
|  |- c.txt
|  |- .d.txt
|  +- c/
|     +- e.txt
|- .b/
   +- f.txt
```

I would like to get

```
a.txt
a/c.txt
a/c/e.txt
```

Any hints?

Comment: You seem to have already got the idea of what to do. Just recursively visit each non-hidden subfolder within a folder and return the non-hidden files. Have you attempted to implement this code already? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really just know `path.rglob("*")` which iterates over everything. No idea how to stop that at hidden directories.

Comment: If the hidden file by your definition is just something that starts with '.', you'd probably just do something like iterating over the `rglob()` output, and at the top of your loop, `if currPath.name.startswith('.'):` with a `continue` statement to skip the loop iteration. You might also have to keep a list of directories that you consider hidden, and prune those paths that are in the blacklist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def non_hidden_files(root):
    for path in root.glob('*'):
        if not path.name.startswith('.'):
            if path.is_file():
                yield str(path)
            else:
                yield from non_hidden_files(path)

print(*non_hidden_files(Path('.')))
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need a `list()` to make use of the generator? Printing it will probably give you the generator object, right?

Comment: @BenY The `*` is for the printing. I made a generator because he wants to _recursively iterate over ..._

Comment: Sorry, missed the asterisk when I tried your code out.